# Is there a program that will only return the constants in a word python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to write a program that asks the user for a word and only returns the constants. But I am stuck with this program, I would expect this program to do what I have mentioned above, but all it does is returns the word row by row.

```
original = input('Enter a word:')
word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
second = word[1]
third = word[2]
fourth = word[3]
fifth=word[4]


if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
    print (first)
else:
    print ("")
if second == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
    print (second)
else:
    print ("")
if third == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
    print (third)
else:
    print ("")
if fourth == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
    print (fourth)
else:
    print ("")
if fifth == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
    print (fifth)
else:
    print ("")
```

Comment: ... *"consonants"*?

Comment: What do u mean by *"constants"* here?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values. Also note that you could significantly simplify this by looping over the input (`for char in word:`) and you've spelled *"fifth"* incorrectly.

Comment: By constants I mean anything that is not A, E, I, O or U

Comment: That is NOT or that IS?

Comment: Is not, so b,c,d,f,g etc

Comment: Those are *"consonants"* (as opposed to *"vowels"*), and that is the **exact opposite** of what your code is even *attempting* to do.

Comment: The letter "o" is feeling lonely and forgotten. :(

Comment: Sorry, but this discussion is hilarious.

Comment: Your right so I should change where i put a e i  to b c d f etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strip all the vowels from a word and print it:

```
original = input('Enter a word:')
print("".join(x for x in original if x.lower() not in "aeiou"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The precedence is wrong. "or" has higher precedence then "==" - see https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

So the line:

```
if first == "a" or "e" or "i" or "u":
```

Is the same as:

```
if (first == "a") or ("e") or ("i") or ("u"):
```

Which I suspect isn't what you wanted. The following might work better:

```
if first in "aeiu":
```

However also note this is case sensitive...